# How to filter an entity in hibernate with hibernate filters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-filters

I need to filter an entity in a list of objects, for example:

```
public class Student {

    private int id;

    private List<Course> courses;

}

public class Course {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private float note;

    private Classroom classroom;

}

public class Classroom {

    private int id;

    private String classroom;

}
```

How to obtain a student object with a list of courses with only notes greater than 70, and located in classroom 23 (for example)?

Is there a way to use the name of the entity instead of the one of the column of the database?

Or how do I associate with sql the alias generated by hibernate for the entity?

I attach a link from the hibernate filters:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html

Comment: Have you tried any configuration yourself? Maybe you can post it and lets see whats wrong with it. Did you get any errors etc.

Comment: I just want to know if it can be filtered by the java entity, not by the database entity.

Comment: And how to do the join with the alias that generates hibernate dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok it think this should do the trick:

**Entities**

```
public class Student {

    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @Filter(name = "defaultCoursesFilter")   
    private List<Course> courses;

}

@FilterDef(name = "defaultCoursesFilter"
                , defaultCondition=" notes > 70")
public class Course {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private float note;

    @ManyToOne
    @Filter(name = "defaultClassromFilter")
    private Classroom classroom;

}


@FilterDef(name = "defaultClassromFilter"
                , defaultCondition=" id  = 23")
public class Classroom {

    private int id;

    private String classroom;

}
```

**Before query**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.enableFilter("defaultCoursesFilter");
session.enableFilter("defaultClassromFilter");

// query
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try.