# Filter one-to-many children while requesting parent Entity with HSQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hello there is my model

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<User> users;

    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}

@Entity
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private boolean valid;


    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

Is it possible to make a HSQL request to select a Group by id, but keeping in the User list, only the users with 'true' in the "valid" field ?

Comment: In which framework you are writing the query means hibernate/eclipselink/jdbctemplate etc or using JPA EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HSQL to return JPA entity tree (simple way), the **answer is no**.
Though, you can write this:

```
select g from Group g
left join g.users u with u.valid = true
where g.id = 123
```

your `users` collection won't be initialized. If you add `fetch` keyword to the join, you get an error:

> QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters

Which leads you to other solution, [using annotation `@Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821516/how-to-filter-an-entity-in-hibernate-with-hibernate-filters). But you need to enable the filter, and then you have problem with updating the entity read with the filter turned on (collection synchronization).